# Can we send and receive uTorrent packets through TOR?

Tags: tor, python, packet, bittorrent

I just started using pcapy python module to capture network packets. Is it possible to capture packets going out from uTorrent (on my own machine) with `pcapy` or `scapy` and sending them over the TOR network? And after receiving the response packets, direct them to uTorrent?

If it is possible, then what are the work arounds?

Comment: [Bittorrent over Tor isn't a good idea](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/bittorrent-over-tor-isnt-good-idea)

Comment: Assume that we aren't concerned about privacy

Comment: Torrent traffic is still a large load on the TOR network, please don't do it.

Comment: This isn't an InfoSec question but a pcapy or scapy programming question.

Comment: I'm not making a commercial product and @schroeder I'm not asking for code. What I saying is "In theory is it possible to send those packets over TOR and direct them back to client? Because Torrent is based on a peer to peer network ( not usual Server Client connection) "

Comment: But you want to do it with a specific python module.  That makes it a programming question. Or, at best, this is a TOR protocol question. Neither are InfoSec questions.

Comment: There is a TOR forum on stackexchange that might help, or someone on stackoverflow might have more knowledge of pcapy/scapy.

Comment: I mentioned those python modules because TORproject provides Stem APIs which are also written in Python to interact with TOR